# Can I travel from India to Australia and back and within Australia if the first cover page of my passport is slightly stained and faded-image attached

Tags: passports

[image: 1st cover page of my passport]Can I travel from India to Australia and back and within Australia if the first cover page of my passport is slightly stained and faded. All other pages are intact. Please advise.